# UML class diagram reference: for group function of a webapp. (like facebook group)

Tags: uml

I am looking for some existing references of the UML class diagram that is model for "group function of a webapp system", like facebook group or meetup.com etc.

basically, creating groups, request joining groups, accept , reject, create events in the group, join events..etc.

I just want to see how ppl model that specific part of the web app (group functions), and see some common references of what would be a good way to model that!

I have hand draw a class diagram -[image]

what I am trying to model is:

1. User can join 0 to many groups
2. Group can have 1 to many users
3. Group has 0 to many events
4. User can be invited to the event of their group, the user can accept / reject..etc.
5. Group can send their event (activity) to other groups and they can also accept / reject .etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Class diagrams are STRUCTURE diagrams. And you are talking about behaviour. It is extremely inconvenient to show behaviour in class diagrams. Start from use cases and go to activity diagrams.
2. UML is a language set, supporting modelling. Not modelling in some specific language, let alone programming language or specific framework. I sometimes use class diagrams for modelling UI design or user guides. ***UML diagrams look the same, no regard to use of facebook***.
3. Facebook programming is a use of a framework, supporting creation some kinds of IS, with some ready functionalities. If you want to make a class diagram supporting such modelling, simply use the facebook classes as ready ones and derive your classes from them.

Edit.
As reaction to your diagram (please, put its reference into the question):

- Two-sided shared aggregation is forbidden in UML standard. I see, it HAS sense, but you must write it as two connections.
- `Group`-`event` connection has diamond on the wrong end.
- `Group` or `User` or both should have `invite` method
- What user *can* do is to be set in use case or state diagram, not in class diagram.  The same for your rule 5

Again - you should start from UC diagram or state diagram.

Comment: Ok I think my question is not clear enough.
I just want to see how ppl model that specific part of the web app (group functions), just happen ppl know what facebook group is. I just want to see some common references of what would be a good way to model that!

Comment: @Jaxox Then I am afraid, you are asking a forbidden question here. Such "example" will be a ready backbone for your work. Here on the StackOverflow you must do the main bulk of the work yourself and ask for some problems you have met. Show us the all-done-by-you use case and partly-done-by-you class diagram and we'll help you to develop it correctly.

Comment: Ok, I have a simple UML class diagram.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B60mNP2z_R1Oak1XQWxaNHJsZlB1VHNLUGRvbVQzQk9xc0Yw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks @Gangnus. but aren't those actions need to be recorded and better to have the association class for those information?

Comment: @Jaxox If you want to set the list of actions - use UC diag. Actions/states - state diag. Actions structure - activity diag. Sequences of actions - Sequence diag. Timing - timing diag. You also can include classes there. But the Class diag is NOT for actions. Learn how to use behaviour diagrams.

Comment: @Jaxox Now your diag is much better. But you use association classes incorrectly. Your invitations are ACTIONS, not objects that contain all info about associations. Your task is too simple for using association classes.

Comment: Thanks @Gangnus. the idea is to store the response and the info of the invitation, e.g. "invitation status" yes/no/maybe etc, "time period" 1/2/3 days of the invitation, it is not just an action to send out the invitation!

Comment: @Jaxox Yes, if they rather become registration cards than invitations, than they SHOULD be association classes, it is correct. You have mentioned them in the question only as actions, so sorry for misunderstanding...

Comment: @Jaxox But that you have forgotten to connect GroupInvitation to the appropriate association.

Comment: I am more looking for what is the best practice to create this type of Group, event function! how would you model such system? and can you explain why is a better approach than others??

Answer (score 0):

I can't access your drawing, so i can't see what you have done.

As a starting point, this shows the **entities**, **relationships** and **cardinalities**.

[image]

I have not included a relationship between user and event, because this is implicit through group. You may or may not want to visually draw in that relationship.

This only shows the static structure of the system and does not show the dynamic aspects.